# How to rewrite setState from class component to useState in functional component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, color-picker

I want to use this color picker in my React project https://casesandberg.github.io/react-color/#about

Here is example from docs

```
import React from 'react';
import { SketchPicker } from 'react-color';

class Component extends React.Component {
  state = {
    background: '#fff',
  };

  handleChangeComplete = (color) => {
    this.setState({ background: color.hex });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <SketchPicker
        color={ this.state.background }
        onChangeComplete={ this.handleChangeComplete }
      />
    );
  }
}
```

But it's class component. I have functional with useState in my project. One of them is

```
const [projectColor, setProjectColor] = useState("#F9A8D4");
```

with default picked color.
**How to rewrite this class example to use with usestate?** I don't get it...

```
onChangeComplete={ this.handleChangeComplete }
```

is like setState? And from where is this color variable?

```
handleChangeComplete = (color) => {
    this.setState({ background: color.hex });
  };
```

Here is my full code (i don't know what pass to the setProjectColor).
Colors is array with colors to pick, and color is default selected color.

```
const [projectColor, setProjectColor] = useState("#F9A8D4");
  const colors = [
    "#FECACA",
    "#F9A8D4",
    "#FDE68A",
    "#A7F3D0",
    "#BFDBFE",
    "#E5E7EB",
  ];

  const colorPicker = () => {
    return (
      <div className="p-4">
        <CirclePicker
          colors={colors}
          color={projectColor}
          onChangeComplete={(e) => setProjectColor(projectColor)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to use the `color` object of `onChangeComplete` callback:

```
onChangeComplete={(color) => setProjectColor(color.hex)
```

Full example:

```
const [projectColor, setProjectColor] = useState("#F9A8D4");

return (
  <div className="p-4">
    <CirclePicker
      colors={colors}
      color={projectColor}
      onChangeComplete={(color) => setProjectColor(color.hex)}
    />
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your function:

```
 handleChangeComplete = (color) => {
    this.setState({ background: color.hex });
  };
```

into:

```
const handleChangeComplete = React.useCallback((color) => setProjectColor(color), []);
```

Comment: You don't need `useCallback` since the setter function of `useState` is stable.

Comment: No, you need, becaue in case of `onChangeComplete={(color) => setProjectColor(color.hex)}` your callback will be re-created every time component is re-rendered. Also it will affect re-rendering of all children components because reference is changed

Comment: In your example you can just pass `onChangeComplete={setProjectColor}`

Comment: Yeah, it's also ok , though I prefer having a separate callback because usually after some time you need to add some additional logic, so you anyway refactor your code and adding a separate callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the class as the code below

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import { SketchPicker } from 'react-color';

function FComponent() {
    const [background, setBackground] = useState('#fff');

    const handleChangeComplete = useCallback((color) => {
        setBackground(color.hex);
    }, []);

    return (
        <SketchPicker
            color={background}
            onChangeComplete={handleChangeComplete}
        />
    );
}
```

Some explanation to the differences from React.Component and React.FunctionalComponent:

- `React.Component`s are instantiated as an object. The object are mutable and when you call a method, you will always see all its attributes up to date (when you have access to component's `this`, you can always see the current props and state objects). The state is managed internally and you can update it with `this.setState` function.
- `React.FunctionalComponent`s are simply functions. All the variables and functions declared inside it belong to its scope (very important when we use hooks inside a FC). The state is managed externally to the function scope, using `useState` hook, that provides mutability through each renders. To be compliant to React behavior (new property to component triggers its rerendering) **it is necessary do not declare functions inside the FC component but use the `useCallback` hook instead**, cause each render means new function and maybe a useless rerendering of sub components.
  See also https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html